# Shell -e command

Tags: shell, syntax

I came across [this shell script](https://gist.github.com/erikh/2260182) for OSX and I don't understand the following:

`[ -e ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/*.db ]` on line 191?

What is that command doing? I've also seen things like `[ -r "$file" ]`. I don't completely understand this syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-e` is an argument to `[` command (which is an alias of `test`; you can read the full docs with `man test`).  It means «if the file or directory exists».  This line is harmless unless `[` was redefined earlier.